# Error: Could not find 1 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages: - Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error in a Xamarin Forms application.  I have migrated my application to AndroidX.

Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.1.0.0/build/monoandroid90/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(9,9): Error: Could not find 1 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:
 - Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources
You can also copy-and-paste the following snippet into your .csproj file:

I have deleted my bin and obj folders and tried to rebuild to no avail.

I have gone back and done a clean/rebuild to no avail.

I have made sure that all my Xamarin.AndroidX nugets to make sure that they are up to date, and am using the nugets from February 14, 2020.

I am using the Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.282-pre4.  I need this because of some updates to use WkWebView in some web content that I display in the iOS side.  the iOS side compiles just fine.

I'm using the most upto date VSMac in the stable channel.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?  I'm up for any ideas.  TIA.

Comment: According to your description, you mean that you have this issue when you migrate your project to AndroidX? Your project have no issue before.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT According the my project, everything has been running fine.  I have now switched from VSMac to VSWin, and the project compiles and deploys in debug mode to my Pixel3.  I have switched back to VSMac and now it is working.  Weird.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. I solved it installing the following Nuget packages

```
Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4
Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData
Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration
```

In general take a look at the tool output who is much detailed about what packages are missing

Answer (score 4):

I was busting my head over the same issue. Migrating "packages.config" to "PackageReferences" worked for me!

You can find more details here in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Comment: Would be nice if you could elobrate on the steps you did.

Comment: can you post an snippet please

Comment: @NagarajAlagusudaram If you go to <projectName>.Android you need to use PackageReferences

Answer (score 0):

I already saw a similar trouble here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/4#issuecomment-565702561

If this does not help, could you show your list of packages or create a separate project with minimal settings so that I can deal with this situation?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I went through the 4 steps (I didn't uninstall the support libraries).  I did not have any more luck.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/323gv  I have pasted the contents of my packages.config file into the link.

Comment: I have now switched from VSMac to VSWin, and the project compiles and deploys in debug mode to my Pixel3.  I have switched back to VSMac and now it is working.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how I solved this, or that I have truly solved this, but I know that this is now working correctly.

How?  I decided to try this on VSWin.  Of course it worked from VSWin.  I ran the app on my Pixel3, and it worked.  This morning, I compiled again from VSMac, and it all worked, including deploying again to my Pixel3.

I do not consider that I really answered the question and found a solution.  I just merely think that the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the missing plugins

Error: Could not find 18 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:

- Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser
- Xamarin.Google.Android.Material
- Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4
  You can also copy-and-paste the following snippet into your .csproj file:

Comment: What snippet are you referring to?

Comment: @Denny Referring this Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 is missing

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and tried many things to resolve that, but solution was simple:
Please uninstall and then install again Xamarin.Forms via NuGet.
In my case now everything working well with Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2612